# Access values from .lua file into python

Tags: python, lua

I don't know much about LUA, but i have this really big .lua file which begging's looks like this:

```
return {
  ["Aatrox"] = {
    ["id"]         = 266,
    ["apiname"]    = "Aatrox",
    ["title"]      = "the Darkin Blade",
    ["attack"]     = 8,
    ["defense"]    = 4,

...
```

The file just returns this very big object. My question is: How do I access, let's say the value of Aatrox's defense (which is 4) in my Python script? Take it easy on me, I'm new to lua, and my terminology isn't that great.

Comment: Write the object in the output of the lua script into a JSON file, then read it in the python script.

Comment: yes good ideea, but how do i do the first part? how do i write the output into json?

Comment: There are a lot of Lua JSON libraries.  Even me has [one](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua).  Use a text editor to convert your file `return {big_object}` into `print(require"json".encode{big_object})` and run it in Lua interpreter.  The `json.lua` file must be in subfolder `lua` (for example, you may have `C:\Lua\lua.exe`, `C:\Lua\lua5x.dll` and `C:\Lua\lua\json.lua`)

Comment: thank you @EgorSkriptunoff you saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the lua object into a json file to be able to access it from python with @Egor Skriptunoff 's help from the comments:

> There are a lot of Lua JSON libraries. Even me has one. Use a text editor to convert your file return {big_object} into print(require"json".encode{big_object}) and run it in Lua interpreter. The json.lua file must be in subfolder lua (for example, you may have C:\Lua\lua.exe, C:\Lua\lua5x.dll and C:\Lua\lua\json.lua)