# Setting up LUA on Windows with a JSON module

Tags: json, module, lua

I'm looking for some help in converting a .lua file to JSON. Someone, who uses Linux, has given me a very simple LUA script to convert the .lua to JSON:

```lua
require('json');
dofile "<your file>";

local encoded = json.encode(CensusPlus_Database);
print(encoded);
```

As a disclaimer, I have very little understanding of this kind of stuff and need to start from the beginning. First step was to install LUA. I did it from this website, https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2.4/Tools%20Executables/

I then tried to execute the above LUA script and received the message `"module 'json' not found"`.

Can someone tell me how to install a JSON module please?

Comment: Look at [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157004/access-values-from-lua-file-into-python#comment124020089_70157004)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks for the reply. I've looked at your comment and have created the 'lua' subfolder and downloaded your 'json.lua' library. However, I can't the syntax working to print out the .lua file in JSON formatting. The path of my file is 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\rawData.lua     Please can you write the subsequent commands to print the required output?

Comment: What's inside `rawData.lua`?  Post the beginning and end of the file.

Comment: Start of the file ---- CensusPlus_Database = {
 ["TimesPlus"] = {
End of the file ---- CensusPlus_JobQueue = {
 ["CensusPlus_LoginRealm_last"] = "5264_Kingsfall",
 ["CensusPlus_LoginFaction"] = "",
 ["g_TimeDatabase"] = {
  ["Warrior"] = 0,
  ["Paladin"] = 0,
  ["Shaman"] = 0,
  ["Rogue"] = 0,
  ["Mage"] = 0,
 },
 ["CensusPlus_LoginFaction_last"] = "Horde",
 ["CensusPlus_last_time"] = 1638106814,
 ["CensusPlus_LoginRealm"] = "",
 ["g_TempCount"] = {
 },
 ["g_NumUpdatedCharacters"] = 0,
 ["g_NumNewCharacters"] = 0,
}

Comment: Might be easier to just send you the file? @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Insert the line `print(require"json".encode(CensusPlus_Database))` at the end of the file `rawData.lua` and execute it with Lua.  This will print the `CensusPlus_Database` object only.  Do you need to print the whole .lua file as JSON?

Comment: No, don't need to print the whole file. How would I do that? Anyway, thank you, this allowed me to print the data I need. Cheers!